# How to query a list (which contains code) to another list which contains code and description

Tags: c#

I have List which contains a list of codes

```
List1 {TransCode:'DV' Description:'Delivered',
       TransCode:'TN' Description:'Transfer'... etc.....}

List2 {Code:DV, Code:TN, Code:NA, etc...}
```

I need to find from the `List1` what the `Description` is for my `List2`.

Here's my code so far:

```
List<string> Match  = List1.Where(i => i.TransCode == Code).Select(x => x.Description).ToList();
```

I am getting error message and cannot get the expected result.

Comment: Paste your data structures and the error thanks

Comment: Put together a quick little piece of demo code that demonstrates the lists, how they're populated, and the bit you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response,  "i => i.TransCode == Code" I am getting error -> Operator == cann't be applied to operands of type string to list<string>

Comment: what about creating a separate list of codes like `var codes = List2.Select(s=>s.code).ToList();` then select all `TransCode` matching to the `codes` as  `List<string> Match  = List1.Where(i => codes.Contains(i.TransCode)).Select(x => x.Description).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks you so much Vikscool , it fixed my issuee

Answer (score 0):

You need to join both the list to get matching records. This should fix your error

```
var matchDesc = list2.Join(list1, a => a.Code, b => b.TransCode, (a, b) => b.Desc).ToList();
```